# Why does `(void *)&` get the address of the variable?

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading, c-strings, void-pointers

Could someone explain the logic behind this? Why `void`? For example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char c;
    cout << (void *)&c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cout << (void *)&c;
```

takes the address of `c`, then casts it to `void*`, then prints pointer.

The intent here is to print the address of variable `c`. But when passing a `char *` to `std::cout <<`  it will attempt to print a null-terminated string. To avoid this (and print the actual address) you have to cast to `void*` first.

---

More explanation:

`std::ostream::operator<<` has [overload (2)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) that handles `char *` and `const char*`. It assumes that a `const char*` will point to some string that is eventually terminated by a null-character `'\0'`. That's simply a convention used in C and C++.

You want to avoid this and instead use [overload (7)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) to print the address.

Comment: So would I need to convert it to `void*` when and only when a variable is NULL?

Comment: @anon No. It's only when you want to print the address of a `char`, i.e. a `char *` or `const char*`.

Answer (score 4):

The `operator <<` is overloaded for objects of the type `char *` such a way that it outputs characters as if the used pointer is a pointer to the first character of a C-string (a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`).

And the expression `&c` without casting has the type `char *`. So the operator assumes that the passed pointer expression `&c` supplies a pointer to a C-string.

To output the address of the object `c` you need to cast the expression `&c` to the type `void *`.

Here is a simple program that demonstrates the difference.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "Hello";
    
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<const void *>( s ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
0x5598fd4a3004
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does `(void *)&` get the address of the variable?

The unary `&` is the addressof operator. The addressof operator gets the address of the operand because that's the purpose of that operator.

> Why void?

Because

1. The type of `&c` is `char*`, and pointers of that type are treated by the output stream as a pointer to a null terminated character string, which are handled differently from all other pointers. Specifically, the content of the string would be output. Inserting a `char*` that isn't a pointer to a null terminated character string into a character stream would result in undefined behaviour. `&c` is not a pointer to a null terminated character string. Inserting a pointer of another type into a character stream will instead result in the output of a numerical representation of the address.

   The example converts `&c` to another pointer type so that it won't be treated as a null terminated character string.
2. All object pointers can be converted to `void*`, so that is the pointer type that is conventionally chosen for outputting the address of a character.

---

For a bit more detail, the character stream insert operator has overloads:

```
operator<<(ostrea&, const char*);
operator<<(ostrea&, const void*); // I'm cheating a bit
                                  // this is technically a member overload
```

---

> So would I need to convert it to void* when and only when a variable is NULL?

Not at all. The variable `c` isn't null. And whether a pointer is null has no influence on whether or not it needs to be converted to `void*`.

Also note that null terminator character - which terminates a null terminated string - is not a null pointer. And a null pointer is not a pointer to a null terminator character. Those are entirely different concepts.